# QString exchange in qml through c++

Tags: c++, qml

this example is supposed to read the string from TextInput and display it in another Rectangle on click of the mouse. However, it does not. Why?

```
//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QDeclarativeContext>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class MainWindow : public QDeclarativeView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

class Data : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString teamName READ getTeamName WRITE setTeamName NOTIFY nameChanged)

public:
    Data(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Data();

public:
    QString getTeamName();
    void setTeamName(QString &);

signals:
    void nameChanged();

private:
    QString n_teamName;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

//mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QDeclarativeContext>
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QDeclarativeView(parent)
{

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

Data::Data(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    //n_teamName = "Ahoj";
}

Data::~Data(){

}

QString Data::getTeamName(){
    return n_teamName;
}

void Data::setTeamName(QString &newName){
    if(newName != n_teamName){
        n_teamName = newName;
        emit nameChanged();
    }
}

//main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <qdeclarative.h>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QDeclarativeContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    Data d;
    qmlRegisterType<Data>("NData", 1, 0, "Data");
    w.rootContext()->setContextProperty("data", &d);
    w.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("../klik/Main.qml"));

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

//main.qml
// import QtQuick 1.0 // to target S60 5th Edition or Maemo 5
import QtQuick 1.1
import NData 1.0
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 600
    height: 400
    Rectangle{
        id: text
    ...
        TextInput{
            anchors.fill: text
            anchors.margins: 3
            focus: true
         }
    }
    Rectangle{
    ...
        Text{
            id: copyText
            anchors.centerIn: copy
            text: data.setTeamName()
        }
    }
    Rectangle{
        id: klik
        ...
        MouseArea{
        ...
            onClicked: {
                copyText.text = data.teamName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It lets out the error: TypeError: Result of expression 'data.setTeamName' [undefined] is not a function.
Main.qml:51: Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to QString

Answer (score 0):

`teamName` is a property of `data`, so simply use assign operator like `data.teamName = 'some text';`

Probably you should add `id` field to your `TextInput` like

```
TextInput{
    id: textInput
    anchors.fill: text
    anchors.margins: 3
    focus: true
}
```

And change `onClicked`, so

```
MouseArea{
   ...
    onClicked: {
        data.teamName = textInput.text
        copyText.text = data.teamName // copyText.text = textInput.text is fine too
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there still must be something wrong. I've tried this, but the text is not copied and the error is: Cannot assign [undefined] to QString

Comment: Please check, that object you are trying copying from really exists or show what you are specifically trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your actual exception is due to the following line

```
text: data.setTeamName()
```

setTeamName is a private function on your data object, that is not exposed as a slot, and is thus undefined when called and assigned to text.  Nevermind the fact that it makes no sense to call the set when you are performing an assignment. I'm assuming this was supposed to be data.getTeamName().